# Get conditional string return value : True or False

Tags: python

I have conditional string like below ,

```
condition1 = "((2=2) or (3=1)) and (1=1)"
condition2 = "((2=3) or (1=1)) and (4=5)"
```

Above both condition gives me out-put True and False respectively.

More explanations :

condition1 work as ,

```
if ((2==2) or (3==1)) and (1==1):
      Return True
else:
      Return False
```

Output for condition1 : True

condition2 work as ,

```
if ((2==3) or (1==1)) and (4==5):
      Return True
else:
      Return False
```

Output for condition2 : True

Update :

Sorry Friends,

I have conditional string like above condition1 and condition2.

i want to make function when i parse condition as string and that function perform like if - else and return Boolean value

Please Help...

Thanks
Chintan

Comment: So what's the actual problem here?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.. plz see updated questions and plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning:** Using `eval` is [potentially dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and you should never eval untrusted input (for example *any* kind of user input).

```
In [1]: condition1 = "((2=2) or (3=1)) and (1=1)"
   ...: condition2 = "((2=3) or (1=1)) and (4=5)"
   ...: 

In [2]: eval(condition1.replace('=','=='))
Out[2]: True

In [3]: eval(condition2.replace('=','=='))
Out[3]: False
```

Comment: Obligatory '`eval` is potentially dangerous'. But it is the simplest way.

Comment: @chintu -- You are welcome. Note that eval is "dangerous" and you shouldn't eval untrusted input, that is any kind of user input...

Comment: Thanks for inform me about cons of eval function

Comment: @downvoter -- if there is problem with my answer, I would like to know what i can improve.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to get the condition evaluated and have python give you the True or False output, take a look at the eval() function in python.

Comment: How about simply `eval(condition1.replace('=', '=='))` and  `eval(condition2.replace('=', '=='))` :-)

Comment: @chintu I updated my answer. -- BTW, your conditional strings in your updated question still use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In python, the operator for comparison is `==`.

Either way, you should state more clearly what we should help you with, if that doesn't solve your problem.

**Update:** The function you're looking for to evaluate a string which represents a Python expression is `eval()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but that's not my problem,plz see updated Question... thanks once again

Comment: @chintu I updated my answer. -- BTW, your conditional strings in your updated question still use = instead of ==.

Answer (score 1):

a solution without 'eval'

```
def condition(a,b,c):  
    if (((a[0]==a[1]) or (b[0]==b[1])) and (c[0]==c[1])):  
       return True  
    else:  
      return False
```

print condition((2,2),(3,1),(1,1))  # returns True
print condition((2,3),(1,1),(4,5))  # returns False

Comment: Thanks for reply but not like that... I got the ans.